# Form Submit Handler not firing on Page Reload with GET parameters

Tags: views, hooks

I have a simple form

```
function example_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#attributes']['method'] = 'get';
  $form['button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
  );
  $form['search'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => FALSE,
  );

  return $form;
}
```

and a submit handler

```
function example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  drupal_set_message(t('Form Submitted'));
}
```

When I click the button, the form submits properly and the URL gets all the form parameters.

but when I reload the page with all those URL parameters, the `example_form_submit()` is not firing, how do I make my form submit/fire the submit hook when the URL is reloaded with GET parameters?

Comment: No matter what your submit settings are (GET/POST), it should not trigger the submit handler after a page reload with the same data. A form rendered using the form API adds a submit token to the form that is valid only for that form submission. After a form submit/rebuild (or with a page refresh), the token will be different. So any data transmitted using a browser refresh after the original form was submitted already should not trigger the submit handlers for that form again. (Consider it Drupal's CSRF protection.)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to change the method to be used by a form is to use the `#method` element rather than by setting the attribute, as otherwise the form API will still expect to be triggered by a POST.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#method